# Open source Mac video streaming server solutions?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, macos, video-streaming

In my application, I want to stream videos shot on an iPhone, *.movie files, from a server running on a Mac desktop to an iPhone or iPad client.  What are some possible open source servers that do this that are small enough to be shipped or embedded with a downloadable Mac app?  There is a product StreamToMe by Matt Gallagher that does this.  I noticed a lot of open source alternatives like ffmpeg, VideoLan, and the like but I not sure which one would be good for the Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an app called `iPhone Remote`. It is under Apache license, and should do what you need.

Here is a little [rundown on its features](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/12/06/how-to-stream-audio-and-video-from-your-mac-to-your-iphone-or-ipod-touch/). While it may be an overkill,
it's free, open source and has the streaming feature you may be able to extract.

Here is the [official page](http://code.google.com/p/telekinesis/)